# Angular 6: Return HttpHeaders

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am currently building a small Angular Application for learning purposes. I am calling a .net core WebApi to get / manipulate data.

Now, my question is this:

In all Post and Put requests I am using exactly the same header:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');
```

I append it like this (for e.g. in post):

```
return this.http.post<SmartCard>(AppDefinitions.ApiSmartCardAdminPath, body, { headers })
```

Since both post and put has the same headers, I thought about adding it to my AppDefinitions Class, which looks something like this:

```
import { HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";

export class AppDefinitions {
    public static ApiBasePath: string = "http://<my webapp name>.azurewebsites.net/api/";
    public static ApiLoginPath: string = AppDefinitions.ApiBasePath + "Login/";
    public static ApiSmartCardAdminPath: string = AppDefinitions.ApiBasePath + "SmartCard/";
    public static JsonHttpHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');
}
```

So then I proceeded to remove the ehader definition in the post- and put methods and just replaced it with a call of the JsonHttpHeaders, which then looked like this:

```
return this.http.post<SmartCard>(AppDefinitions.ApiSmartCardAdminPath, body, { this.GetHttpHeaders() })
```

But this only leads to an error, which states:

```
Argument of type '{ this: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'this' does not exist in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
```

Now, I am not sure if I understand this correctly, but does that mean that my AppDefinitions is returning any? How can I change that? I also tried to create the following method in the service class itself:

```
  GetHttpHeaders() : HttpHeaders{
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');
    return headers;
  }
```

But this leads to the same error.

What am I doing (and understanding) wrong?

Comment: You can't use object shorthand (`{ foo: foo }` -> `{ foo}`) unless you're actually using the same name as the property.

Comment: you should pass an object with the key value pairs as mentioned in the error , { headers:this.GetHttpHeaders() }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set headers property.

```
return this.http.post<SmartCard>(AppDefinitions.ApiSmartCardAdminPath, body, { headers: this.GetHttpHeaders() })
```